# How to use multi threading on this for loop to decrease the execution time?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe, for-loop

I have a folder that contains 1000's of folder under which there are 1000's of file.

```
cb = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
        filepath = root + os.sep + name
        df = pd.read_csv(filepath,index_col=False)
        df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.TimeStamp, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        date = df['TimeStamp'].dt.date.values[0]
        time = df['TimeStamp'].dt.time.values[0]
        
        if (df.shape[0] > 0):
               cb.append({'Time': time, 'Date': date})
```

I need to open all the files and do some data processing on them and append the data to empty dataframe.

Doing it sequentially takes days to run, is there a way I can use multiprocessing/threading to reduce the time and not skipping any files in the process?

Comment: You can use Thread Pool. Refer - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-threadpoolexecutor-in-python3/

Comment: As I understand it, you want the first date time values from each CSV. So, there isn't any reason to read the entire file. As an aside, you check `df.shape[0] > 0` _after_ you've already attempted to index the first row. You may want to put that check first.

Comment: That is just an e.g., I need to read files and perform multiple calculations etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the per-file work into a separate function and then use a multiprocessing pool to push the processing to separate processes. This helps with CPU bound calculations but the file reads will take just as long as your original serial processing. The trick to multiprocessing is to keep the amount of data flowing through the pool itself to a minimum. Since you only pass a file name and return a couple of date time objects in this example, you're good on that point.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pandas as pd
import os

def worker(filepath):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath,index_col=False)
    df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.TimeStamp, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    date = df['TimeStamp'].dt.date.values[0]
    time = df['TimeStamp'].dt.time.values[0]

    if (df.shape[0] > 0):
         return({'Time': time, 'Date': date})
    else:
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_files = [root + os.sep + name 
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir)
        for name in files]
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        cb = [result for result in pool.map(worker, csv_files, chunksize=1) 
                if result]
```

Comment: NameError: name 'name' is not defined

How do i accomodate 'name' in this?

csv_files = [root + os.sep + name for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir)]
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        cb = [result for result in mp.Pool.map(worker, csv_files, chunksize=1) 
                if result]

Comment: My bad, forgot to enumerate the names in `files`.

Comment: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'map'
@tdelaney

Comment: Fixed. Should have been `pool.map`, not `Pool.map`.

Comment: Still,   AttributeError: module 'multiprocessing.pool' has no attribute 'map'

Comment: Okay, I'm blind. Left the `mp` module reference in there.